# Put together two arrays then insert to database

Tags: php

I have this two arrays, which come both from some checkbox selections and they are:

```
$date=$_REQUEST['date'];
$pdv=$_REQUEST['checkbox'];
```

The first array lists some dates, what i need is  to loop therough the dates, and insert pdv values selected for that date in the database, something like:

```
[date] [1] => [pdv] [1]
           => [pdv] [2]
           => [pdv] [3]

[date] [2] => [pdv] [1]
           => [pdv] [2]
```

Then i will have this loop which will permit me to insert in the database valus :

```
   [date] [1] - [pdv] [1] ; [date] [1] - [pdv] [2];
```

I thought of using this foreach but i am not that professional with php.. here's where i'm asking for your help..

```
foreach($date as $val) {
foreach ($checkbox as $pdv) {
$values_arr[] = "('" . $val . "','" . $pdv . "')";
}
$values = implode(", ", $values_arr);

$sql="INSERT INTO date (att_id,date) VALUES $values";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, i mean, i should merge values from the first value of the first array with all the values of the second array, then the second value of the first array with all the values of the second array and so on...

Comment: You're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Better learn about those before you go any farther with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many useful functions here, try some of them:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Like this one:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

And use **print_r** for view result array:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($array) ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not exactly the answer to my question but i'll accept the answer, i found what was wrong with my code :)

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not solve your problem :D I'm new for stackoverflow and I can't find how to put comment instead of answer :( Also you can use "echo vardump($var)" instead of print_r

Answer (score 0):

A good way to merge array is to use

```
array_merge_recursive();
```

https://www.php.net/array_merge_recursive